# How do I make a column of 3 cards match in height in bootstrapVue?

Tags: bootstrap-vue

I have a row with 3 columns containing cards, the `b-card-text` (text in the cards) is not equal in length thus making the cards differ in height. Question is how do I make the cards match in height?

Tried adding `h-100 d-inline-block` classes to the cards but no luck.

```html
<b-row>
    <b-col class md="4">
        <b-card>
            <b-card-text>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of </b-card-text>
         </b-card>
    </b-col>

     <b-col class md="4">
        <b-card class="h-75 d-inline-block">
          <b-card-text>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make
           </b-card-text>
       </b-card>

     </b-col>
         <b-col class md="4">
          <b-card>
             <b-card-text>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard
             </b-card-text>
           </b-card>
       </b-col>
</b-row>
```

I expect the cards to be the same in height.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the `<b-row>` add the class `class="align-self-stretch"`, or to make it applicable to only `md` and up breakpoints: `class="align-self-md-stretch"`. And then use the utility class `h-100` on each `<b-card>`

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/ofcxrquz/

See:

https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/reference/utility-classes

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/#align-self